# Sql Query to handle the conversion in columns varchar to int

Tags: sql

I have been struggling to get the column wise result in the standardised form. I want to achieve what’s present in the ERP Status Column with the below conditions.

- If the ERP is below 15 days, then Less than 15 days ageing is required to be split into two parts (within ERP & Outside ERP (0-ERP days}, {ERP+1 to 15 days) with appropriate ageing - upto Ageing bucket of 15 days)
- If ERP is greater than 15 days, then up to ERP all Age bucket would needed to be split within ERP bucket.
- This would attract an additional age bracket upto 45 days..between 31-60 as Fraud accounts have an ERP of 45 days only for respective set of account.
- For cheques & unapplied account where ERP for credit is 180 days & for debit transactions ERP is just one day. Those are required to be reflected separately (as explained)... Unapplied credit account would have ERP only for debit transactions. All credits will always be in within ERP segment.

I have attached the screenshot of the desired results [image]

I tried using the cast and replace function but couldn’t able to understand the ask.

I want to populate the column erp status based on the conditions

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; [edit] your question to (re)tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Considered below conditions from your question

1. ERP is below 15 days

   a. within ERP  (Ageing_Bucket <= ERP)

   b. Outside ERP (Ageing_Bucket > ERP)
2. ERP is greater than 15 days

   a. within ERP  (Ageing_Bucket <= ERP)

   b. Only for fraud accounts with an ERP of 45 days.

   c. Beyond ERP

Are you looking below case statement?

```
CASE 
        -- If ERP is below 15 days
        WHEN ERP <= 15 THEN
            CASE 
                -- Split within ERP and Outside ERP
                WHEN Ageing_Bucket <= ERP THEN 'Within ERP'
                WHEN Ageing_Bucket > ERP THEN 'Outside ERP'
            END
        -- If ERP is greater than 15 days
        WHEN ERP > 15 THEN
            CASE 
                -- Up to ERP, split within ERP bucket
                WHEN Ageing_Bucket <= ERP THEN 'Within ERP'
                -- Additional age bracket up to 45 days
                WHEN Ageing_Bucket <= 45 THEN '31-45 days'
                -- All other cases beyond 45 days
                ELSE 'Beyond 45 days'
            END
    END AS ERP_Status
```

Comment: Yes the logic is correct but the main problem is to convert the varchar columns to int for the calculation. Because the erp columns entries are as follows - 05 days , 10 days , 15 days. What should be done in that case ?

Comment: did you tried CAST(REPLACE(Ageing_Bucket, ' days', '') AS INT) AS Ageing_Bucket ?

Comment: Yes I did but it didn’t work as there are different values in mostly every column like 30-60, 20 days and <15 like that. The column values are exactly same like in screenshot.

Comment: then you have to write the separate user defined function . Pass the value and return should be number with  all your possiblities.

Comment: I tried but not able to follow it through. Anyway thanks for your help.